# Where orWhere Laravel 5.5 logical DB issue

Tags: database, laravel, where-clause, helper

I am in agony

This is my helper

```
$friend_query = Friend::where([
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'friend_id' => $friend_id,
        ])->orWhere([
        'user_id' => $friend_id,
        'friend_id' => Auth::id(),
        ])->first();

        
        

        $friendship = new stdClass();
        $friendship->exist = false;
        $friendship->accepted = false;

        if (! is_null($friend_query))
        {
        $friendship->accepted = $friend_query->accepted;
        $friendship->exist = true;
    }
        var_dump($friendship->exist);
        exit;
        return $friendship;
```

[image]

And when I am logged as 'user_id' => auth::id() - everything is fine but when I am logged as 'friend_id' who got request always var_dump return me true... This is third day I can not find solution. The photo of DB included in post.

Comment: it's not clear what is the problem here :p, can you explain using the numbers of the ids ?

Comment: You can add your friend to your friendlist, first column is user_id which is logged on and send an invitation. Second column is friend_id where we sent an invitation. If friend_id accept our invitation column accepted changed value at 1

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
$friend_query = Friend::where([
                                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                                'friend_id' => $friend_id,
                                ])
                        ->orWhere(function ($query) use($friend_id) {
                                    $query->where([
                                            'user_id' => $friend_id,
                                            'friend_id' => Auth::id(),
                                            ]);
                                })
                        ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
just little syntax error should be

```
->orWhere(function ($query) {
```

but there is one problem - Undefined variable: friend_id

it goes like this

```
function friendship($friend_id){
friend_query = Friend::where([
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'friend_id' => $friend_id,
        ])->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                $query->where([
                                        'user_id' => $friend_id,
                                        'friend_id' => Auth::id(),
                                        ]);
                            })
                    ->first();
... }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to "group" your `where` clauses, you should pass a `closure` instead then perform your condition inside it. Say for example, you want your query to look like this

> SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE (user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?) OR (user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?) LIMIT 1

Then the eloquent version of this would be

```
$friend_query = Friend::where(function ($query) use ($friend_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->where('friend_id', $friend_id);
})->orWhere(function ($query) use ($friend_id) {
    $query->where('friend_id', Auth::id())
        ->where('user_id', $friend_id);
})->first();
```